# what php functions does msodbcsql make available?

Tags: php

I could not figure another method of doing this, so I am not certain it is correct.  In this posting '[How to Configure Microsoft® ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server® on RedHat Linux with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18531010/how-to-configure-microsoft-odbc-driver-11-for-sql-server-on-redhat-linux-with)', the author indicates the end result is to use msodbcsql in php, but it actually ends on the command line, which is not php.  Does anyone know what php functions this library adds to the fray?

Answer (score 1):

It enables you to connect to an mssql server via ODBC. This isn't specifically related to PHP and doesn't provide any PHP functionality, other than that I presume you can connect via odbc/PDO and do what one normally does with those packages.

The question you referenced is about how to install the driver.

See the page for ODBC commands on the PHP docs: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.uodbc.php

This is MS's page about msodbcsql for Linux: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh568451.aspx

Comment: Not `mysqli` in this case, since we're talking about SQL Server.

Comment: @chris oops, I meant mssql but I'm not sure that's right either.

Comment: In trying to connect with PDO, I receive the error 'could not find driver'.  Is it possible to fetch a list of available values for the first argument of PDO->__construct()?  Or is there another way to connect to Azure from a LAMP system?

Comment: Is it possible for me to contact the creator of that posting for clarification?

Comment: Have either of you connected a linux box to Azure?

Comment: @danilo I have not, but MS's documentation does say one can do so with the driver in question.

Comment: @danilo have you installed the PHP SDK for Azure?

Comment: Not yet.  I will look into it.  Is it available for linux?

Comment: @danilo yes, it is - http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/php-download-sdk/